# 15.04 can't connect to password-protected Wifi

Tags: wireless, gui, 15.04, button

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 from Ubuntu 14.10. 
When I try to connect through the GUI to a password protected wifi network I cannot click on the 'connect' button D:

Any quick fix?

[image]

The wireless card works perfectly fine and I am able to connect to wireless networks that do not require a password input... the GUI that I am referring to is the ubuntu pop-up (in the screenshot) that asks me to insert the password. As you can see the "connect" button becomes "red&gray" and I cannot click on it...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a fix, but a good start nevertheless: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos. Also, can you clarify why you can't click Connect. Is anything wrong?

Comment: what GUI ? what's its name ? Are you using kubuntu ? look at journalctl -f output in a terminal to try to pin-poin the source of the problem.

Comment: I am using ubuntu. The wireless card works perfectly fine and I am able to connect to wireless networks that do not require a password input... the GUI that I am referring to is the ubuntu pop-up (in the screenshot) that asks me to insert the password. As you can see the "connect" button becomes "red&gray" and I cannot click on it...

Comment: Also, I guess this guy has the same issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/614894/cant-click-wifi-connect-button-after-upgrade-to-15-04-from-14-10?rq=1

Comment: For now you can make use of rob's comment in the following article. It's working for me.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/613764/cant-enable-wifi-on-ubuntu-15-04

Comment: You don't seem to use the default GUI theme. Have you tried to revert to the default theme and tried again ?

Comment: This issue is fixed with the latest minor update which I got 2 days before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure that:

1. I typed the right password (silly, but happens more often than not!)
2. restart network manager
3. delete saved connection and add it back again (make sure to select the right authentication system)

Comment: 1. That's not the case, I cannot click that button regardless of what I write.  2. Does not help...  3. I will try asap but this happens also for a network to which i Connected just fine until the upgradr, than everything went tumbling down... D:

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it by deletin the connections and creating them again, this time I unticked the option "ask everytime for the password".

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04 I can't connect if The Key is showed.
But I dont know if that is the case, maybe try retyping the password or rebooting the Internet

Comment: That's not the case and rebooting the internet does not help...

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem in ubuntu and got it to work today.

The way I got it to work was installing the cinnamon desktop.  (I realize this may not be the place to post this, but it worked for me.) This was a crucial problem as I couldn't use my laptop at work.

From there I had the same issue..when I was prompted to enter a password it would not let me click. I think it may be a permission issue.

I right clicked network settings tab (again in Cinnamon) and it allowed me to enter and save a password. Now I am connected to the wifi.

This may not be the ideal series of events to use, but this is what I did and it is now working.